# saving a section of the screen with screenshot xcode 4.2

Tags: objective-c, ios5, xcode4.2, screenshot

In my app i have a ui image view with a section removed overlaid on top of another image view so the user can upload a pic from  camera roll and manipulate on screen.  I want to save both these images together  using the following code to take a shot of the screen.  However as that aslo takes the top bar and tab view along the bottom, Is it possible to specify a certain area of the screen to save via a screen shot button?

Can I manipulate the following code so it doesn't take a screen shot with the whole screen so I can leave out the bar buttons?

```
if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)])
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.window.bounds.size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
else
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);
[self.view.window.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(viewImage, nil, nil, nil);
```

Comment: Why has this been marked down? Is this not a place to ask programming questions? Perhaps the person who did mark this down would care to explain?

Answer (score 3):

Well you can always create an image from an `UIView`,

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view.bounds.size);
[view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

So, basically instead of taking layer from entire window's view...You just take layer from the the view which you are interested in and then create image from it.

and then save the image to anywhere you want.

Comment: Thanks for advice, sounds a brilliant idea in principal however i cant seem to implement it. Keep getting the following error:    `Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_OBJC_IVAR_$_UIViewController._view", referenced from:
      -[zoompic savepic:] in zoompic.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
`